# Android Bluetooth PBAP

Tags: android, bluetooth, profile

I'm gonna try to introduce briefly what I'm working on, and
then present my question... any help will be very much appreciated!

I've been trying to connect an Android device to other phones in order
to import their phonebook info over bluetooth, using the phonebook
access profile. To achieve that, I'm trying to place my device as PCE,
while the other phone will act as the PSE.

I know that the PSE role is already implemented on Android, so I'm
looking into its code and trying to somehow reverse engineer it to
implement the other side.

So.. my problem is: when the server socket is created, it doesn't
specify any UUID, it simply starts listening on a port 19, like this:

```
mServerSocket = mAdapter.listenUsingRfcommOn(PORT_NUM);
```

Wasn't it supposed to register the PBAP service somewhere? How does
other devices discover the service, and more important, which UUID
should I use when trying to connect in my PCE device with:

```
mSocket = mDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID_PBAP);
```

Thanks, Pedro.

Comment: Were you able to make the PBAP client? If yes can you please guide me regarding what one must do to get the phonebook details after establishing the PBAP connection? This is what I could do so far http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23948610/how-to-query-remote-mobile-phone-via-bluetooth-as-to-whether-it-supports-pbap-or

Answer (score 1):

you should use uuid to create a client socket, sdp will find the crosponding channel for you.

you need not care about the channel number and the channel you assign is not always right in various.

Comment: Question is about how the server side (PBAP PSE) is registered and how the client can discover using SDP without a seeming a correct server side registration. This answer is just says to use SDP but does not explain the why and how it would work. The question can also be clearer to explain the results of the SDP query - did it work? or not? If it worked, then probably the UUID-RFCOMM channel is being registered somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

please use this method:listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord   of BluetoothAdapter with the right UUID.